# por que da error en linea de PhP?

Tags: php, mysql

El codigo es el siguiente estoy haciendo previa consulta desde mySQL.

```
<?php
include_once "conex.php";

$resultado1 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto1 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 1 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado1);
print "$result1[0]"
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto2 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 2 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado2);
print "$result2[0]"
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto3 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 3 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result3 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado3);
print "$result3[0]"
?>
```

si coloco solo que imprima el (**print "$result1[0]"**) comentado el **print "$result2[0]"** y el **print "$result3[0]"** con sus consultas. lo realiza muy bien pero cuando coloco o mejor dicho descomento desde la segunda linea en adelante me da error ¿alguien me ayuda? creo que segun mis conocimientos la linea "parece" bien pero el error sale al agregar la segunda consulta.

el error es el siguiente:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\config\mostrar.php on line 7**

**PD: TODAS las consultas y subconsultas PUEDEN alterarse, pues TODAS hansido Probadas y comprobadas el problema NO ES DE MySQL es de PhP que no se ve donde espera el valor de variable.**

Comment: Incluye en tu pregunta la estructura de la tabla sr_prductos y algunos datos de prueba, por favor. De paso, revisa los logs de apache para ver si arroja algún error al ejecutar la consulta.

Comment: dices que al ejecutar la segunda te da error, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade que error muestra

Comment: id_producto3 tienes este campo en tu base?

Comment: Las comillas no tienen sentido y te faltaría el punto y coma depsues del print . Por Ejemplo print $result1[0];

Comment: Tienes dos variables $resultado2, te faltan los ";", tampoco entiendo por qué tendrías en una tabla diferentes campos con ID pero en correlativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era mas facil solo habia que detallar que una variable estaba repetida por eso hacia error.

```
$resultado1 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto1 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 1 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado1);
print "$result1[0]"
**$resultado2** = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto2 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 2 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado2);
print "$result2[0]"
**$resultado2** = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre_esp,cantidad FROM sr_productos WHERE id = (SELECT id_producto3 FROM sr_escalas_detalle WHERE orden = 3 ORDER BY Orden ASC LIMIT 1)");$result3 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado3);
print "$result3[0]"
?>
```

Al ajecutarse $resultado2 chocaba con la sentencia anterior. los puntos y comas los vote como bien pero el complemento aun si  colocar el print iva a dar ese error. por eso cada variable debe ser unica en php

Answer (score 2):

No se estan incluendo ";" despues de cada print

```
print "$result1[0]"; // ; para fin de sentencia
```

Es necesario incluir ";" despues de cada sentencia. Aunque es opcional (pero recomendable) para la ultima sentencia del fichero.

Tambien es recomendable que cada linea de código este en su propia linea para mas claridad por lo que la sentencia:

```
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultado1);
```

Seria mas apropiada en su propia linea